# Sending props in React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Im trying to send the hook cart to another component, i dont understand how you send props in typescript. I'm just trying to display the cart data in to the sidebar component. Thanks in advance.

```
export type ItemType = {
      id: number;
      name: string;
      price: number;
      content: string;
      image: string;
      amount: number;
    }

    const Cardsitem = ({ id, name, image, content, price, amount }: ItemType) => {
      
      const [cart, setCart]:any[] = useState([]);
    
      const addToCart = (product: any) => {
        setCart([...cart, {...product, name, price, amount: 1}]);
        console.log(cart)
      };
    
      return (
        <Card>
          <CardInfo>
            <img src={image}></img>
          </CardInfo>
    
          <CardOverview>
            <span style={{ marginBottom: -5, fontSize: 20 }}>{name} </span>
            <p style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>
              {content} <br /> {price},-{" "}
            </p>
            <Button onClick={() => addToCart(product)}>Buy</Button>
          </CardOverview>
        </Card>
      );
    };
```

So im trying to send the cart state to another component called sidebar.tsx.

```
        const Sidebar = ({ show }: IProps) => {
  return (
      {...show ? <SidebarContainerActive>
        // Want to display the cart products here 
        </SidebarContainerActive> : <SidebarContainer/>}
  );
};
```

Comment: Its little confusing . you want to pass the cart state to the SideBar Component ? . If yes then i don't see the Sidebar component getting rendered inside the return of `Cardsitem` . Can you please be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that the `Sidebar` is not a child of the component where you set your `card` state via the `useState` hook.

You can only pass props **props** to children. So a thing you can do here is [to lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

So if your App structure currently perhaps looks like the following and your `card` state is defined in the `Card` component (e.g. where the arrow is), you can't pass the `card` state to the `Sidebar` component conveniently.

```
                      App.tsx
                     /       \
               Home.tsx     Sidebar.tsx
                   /   
-->          Card.tsx
```

But if you put your `const [cart, setCart]:any[] = useState([]);` state higher into the hierarchy (in this illustration e.g. `App.tsx` where I put the arrow) you can then pass the `cart` prop down to the `Card` component as well as the `Sidebar` component:

```
-->                   App.tsx
                     /       \
               Home.tsx     Sidebar.tsx
                   /   
             Card.tsx
```